# Is the induction correct in this proof of $R/(I_1\cdots I_k) \cong R/I_1 \times \cdots \times R/I_k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, induction, proof-explanation, chinese-remainder-theorem

From *Algebra, Chapter $0$* by Aluffi:

> [image]
>   [image]

---

In the second line of the proof, he writes assume the statement is known for fewer ideals, but then says we have to prove it for the case of *two* ideals.

It seems like something is incorrect here.

Isn't the induction hypothesis already assuming that $R \to \big(R/(I_1 \cdots I_{k-1})\big) \times R/I_k$ is surjective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is completely fine. By induction hypothesis we assume that $R \rightarrow R/I_1 \times \dots \times R/I_{k-1}$ is surjective if the the ideals $I_j$ and $I_l$ are pairwise coprime for all $1 \leq j \neq l \leq k - 1$. Now we consider the map $R \rightarrow R/I_1 \times \dots \times R/I_{k-1} \times R/I_k \cong R/I_1 \cdots I_{k-1} \times R/I_k$. Thus we deal with the two ideals $I_1 \cdots I_{k-1}$ and $I_k$ (which are coprime under the assumption that $I_j$ and $I_l$ are pairwise coprime for all $1 \leq j \neq l \leq k$) and their quotients which means we have to show it for the case of two ideals.